# How do I determine the URL to the database?

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed and created local MySQL test databases and tables on my Windows 7 PC. In order to connect to the database in Java, I need the parameters of the DriverManager getConnection API which includes the username and password and the URL to the database.

How do I determine the URL to the database?

Comment: You know the machine name, database name, driver name, username and password.  So where exactly the problem?

Comment: http://razorsql.com/docs/help_mysql.html

Comment: Look in the reference guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC URL Format is the following

> jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databasename

The hostname is where your server is installed. So in your case, as you are running the program where MySQL is installed, you can use `localhost`

Again, with default installation the MySQL server listens to the `3306` port, which can be used here.

And finally `database` is the name of your database.

For `username` and `password` you simply add them as a query parameter, so the final result would be

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?username=someusername&password=somepassword`

Reference to the documentation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Good information.  Thanks.